# Cocos2D kazmath/kazmath.h file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, directory

In my app, I am upgrading from Cocos2D version 1.10->2.0-rc0a.

So I did everything the right way as far as I know, the problem I think just has to do with the user header search path.

So my Cocos2D files are **within** a folder **within** a folder **within** a folder **within** a folder, which is on my Desktop. So the actual cocos2D files are 4 folders within until it gets to the desktop.

And my user header search path looks like this:

```
"/Users/myname19/Desktop/NewMyAppBeta/MyApp3/MyApp3"
```

So the full error is: Lexical or Preprocessor Issue, 'kazmath/kazmath.h' file not found in CCNode.h. There are actually **4** of these issues but they are identical.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you also including $(inherited) and $(SRCROOT) in the search path?

Comment: Yep I added a suffix and prefix of quotation marks if thats okay, and also I do this both in my target settings AND project settings and still no luck. I do NOT click that little box to the left of each line also if that makes any difference.

Comment: I think the only one that doesn't need to have quotes is $(inherited).  As for custom frameworks, I just added a new entry with the full file name path (granted, I did this with dropbox, not cocos).

Comment: No luck. Is SRCRoot or inherited supposed to change to anything else when you enter it is it supposed to stay like it is? Also what above that box next to each line, should I enable it or not?

Comment: they should both change.  "$(SRCROOT)/../.." leads to the top level of your project.  %inherited didn't do anything though.'

Comment: SRCRoot does not change for some unknown reason. Also I tried adding your /../.. to the end for both settings and that didn't fix it either.

Comment: Wait, is this in framework, or header search paths?  Because if you're searching for a framework...

Comment: No these are header search paths. They are a bunch of files which you drag into your project but require header search paths.

Comment: the slash in kazmath/kazmath.h indicates a framework though

Comment: I guess it is both. Turns out I did not did not drag kazmath folder in but it has 2 sub-folders which have different content. I am not sure if I need both or one or the other so if your not experienced with Cocos2D I'm not sure if you can answer this :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Did you try turning it off and on again?

Meaning: check if the kazmath.h file is actually there where it's supposed to be. If not, copy it respectively the entire kazmath folder. It's **not** under the cocos2d folder but in a separate "external" folder so chances are you might have missed to copy it into your project.

Comment: Yep that ended up being the issue. Thanks!

Comment: I did this and it still didn't resolve the problem.  I have cocos2d and external as peer folders in my project.  external contains Box2d, Chipmunk, JSCocoa, kazmath and libpng even though I don't use all of them.  Is there anything else I can try?  I'm using cocos2d-iphone-2.0-rc2

Comment: My problem ended up being a space in my project path.  Here's how to solve it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704783/compile-error-in-empty-cocos2d-2-0-iphone

Comment: @MattBecker I am having the same problem.. did u manage to solve it or should we open a different SO question? It might be related to the rc version.. just a guess..

Comment: @mm24, I'm going to write a post about it eventually since it was such a pain, but this is what I ended up doing.  My project has a single folder called Cocos2dEmbeddedWithin, inside that folder I have a libs folder containing the cocos2d folder and the kazmath folder, which in turn contains include and src.  For my "Header Search Paths" I have "Cocos2dEmbeddedWithin/libs/kazmath/include".  Also, there are no spaces in any of the directories of any of the paths.  That got rid of the kazmath problems, then it was onto the ARC issues and missing frameworks :)

Comment: Make sure you drag only the /external/kazmath/include/kazmath folder and not the /external/kazmath folder

Answer (score 6):

Little workaround that worked for me.

I was using Xcode 4.5.1.

I included cocos2d library in my project, and after that I have included kazmath library from external folder.

I replaced all occurrences of  "kazmath/kazmath.h" with "kazmath.h" and all "kazmath/GL/something.h" with "something.h". After that, everything has been built ok.

Comment: I also did this and it worked, though I have to say that it didn't feel like the right way to approach the problem.

Comment: Try this answer: This will work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704783/compile-error-in-empty-cocos2d-2-0-iphone

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to include the double quotes.
something like 
"${SRCROOT}/TestProjet1/libs/kazmath/include" (also with recursive option selected)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

All you need to do is to add the path to the kazmath headers to 
**Build Settings > Header search paths**

for example lib/kazmath/include

Answer (score 1):

Go to Build Settings then Search for Header Search Paths. 
There add relative path of kazmath folder.

```
"./lib/kazmath/include"   //Where . is project directory.
```