# Cocos2D and Xcode 4 - Compiler errors using templates

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I just installed the cocos2d templates in Xcode 4. When I create a new project from the template and run it, it shows around 30 compiler errors. Even without making any changes to the template. Do you have any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Please name the errors. Also, I believe that there is some help available with a little Google search (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704783/compile-error-in-empty-cocos2d-2-0-iphone or http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/15100)

Answer (score 0):

Please add some more information about errors, but it looks like you forgot to add to your project OpenGLES and QuartzCore frameworks. I could be wrong...

Answer (score 0):

I just spent 10 or 15 minutes plus fixing a bunch of errors in this situation, so i will guess:  moving to Xcode 4.X caused many problems for cocos2d projects (including Kobold2D) and most of them require putting "(unsigned int)" in front of an argument in a list of arguments to a 'string with format' type operation creating mostly debug type output.  usually the argument in question is "self", but sometimes just other "types" that resolve to (or can) unsigned ints. in a few cases I had no arguments but a reference to the error string to %@; these required adding a ", self" between the end of string and the close paren. in about 5 to 10% of cases, "fixits" were provided to automate the correction (usually changing the format character to match the argument).  Hope this helps! Happy to provide examples if this actually helps anyone.